# css sprites changing after the website is completed

Tags: css

Is there a better way to change few images from a single file which was generated for CSS Sprites.

As I have a big image file which contains 50 small images and my css uses Sprites. Now I wants to chage 4 button's colors and size of s pointers. What will be the best possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any CSS Sprites Generator like [Spritemapper](http://yostudios.github.com/Spritemapper/).

BTW, I create [ZeroSprites](http://zerosprites.com/) which is an online sprites generator aimed at area minimization using VLSI floorplanning algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your sprite file in a image software like Photoshop or GIMP.

Add new images on the bottom of the existing sprite file. That way, you can keep the existing positions of your sprites.

If you want to find to the css pointers, use the measuring tools in your image software.

Comment: OP wants to change size of existing images

Comment: OP isn't talking about adding new images. They're talking about changing existing images in the sprite, and in some cases making them larger. This would mean the existing positions cannot stay the same.

Comment: unless there is some really clever sprite managing software, there is no better solution than doing it manually.